# How to read video from diffrent folder and creating Video object in matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, directory

I have a lot of videos to run which are kept in the diffrent folder than my current directory of Matlab and VideoReader is not taking the directory address of the video. Need help in creating video object of video kept in a diffrent folder.

```
filePattern = fullfile(pwd, 'videoDir\videoname.mp4');
fileList = dir (filePattern );
video_name =fileList.name;
obj = VideoReader(video_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The .name field of the directory structure is only the final part of the name - it does not include any folders or subfolders. Your very first line defines the entire absolute path and filename for the video file. You can pass that to VideoReader directly.

```
filePattern = fullfile(pwd, 'videoDir\videoname.mp4');
obj = VideoReader(filePattern);
```

In fact, there's no reason you need the 'fullfile' call unless you are going to want to reference this file from a different directory at some later date.

```
obj = VideoReader('videoDir/videoname.mp4');
```

For a more flexible version of this, consider we have a bunch of *.mp4 files in a bunch of sub-directories and we want to step through all of them.

```
Directory = dir('*/*.mp4'); % this command works on Windows or Linux
for jj = 1:length(Directory)
    obj(jj) = VideoReader(fullfile(Directory(jj).folder,Directory(jj).name));
end
```

Comment: Perhaps `fullfile(pwd,'videoDir','videoname.mp4')` would be even better

Comment: Of course :) Was just thinking for future readers, since they might not necessarily be on Windows.